# How to fix this "AttributeError" in python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've googled my error message "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'", but I still can't find out how to fix this error. Please help!

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import io
import sys

sys.stdout=io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('蘋果今日焦點')
dom = requests.get('http://www.appledaily.com.tw/appledaily/hotdaily/headline').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(dom, 'html5lib')
for ele in soup.find('ul', 'all').find_all('li'):
    print(
        ele.find('div', 'aht_title_num').text,
        ele.find('div', 'aht_title').text,
       # ele.find('div', 'aht_pv_num').text
    )
print('---------------------------------')
print('自由今日焦點')
dom = requests.get('http://news.ltn.com.tw/list/breakingnews').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(dom, 'html5lib')
for ele in soup.find('ul','list').find_all('li'):
    print(ele.find('p').text)
```

The error I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ch3-news.py", 
line 23, in <module> print(ele.find('p').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: Think about what happens when `ele.find('p')` doesn't actually find any `'p'` element, and returns `None` (which apparently is what's happening here).

Comment: That's because the returned dom does not contain any <P> tag; ele.find('p') results in a None object

Comment: I'm curious that why line 23 still print things out, if 'p' element can't return anything back. These are my result and they are absolutely what I want. However, I get the error above.```自由今日焦點
小葉日本台》璀璨傳奇，波瀾萬丈，日劇中看見那些有名人                                                    
這間美國公司目標年底IPO 創辦人已套現逾217億 ```

Comment: Perhaps there are *some* list elements which contains a `p` element, then there are some that doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

You could change to use `select` and write css selectors that will can only return existing child `p` tags

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dom = requests.get('http://news.ltn.com.tw/list/breakingnews').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(dom, 'html5lib')
for ele in soup.select('ul li p ,  list li p'):
    print(ele.text)
```